# C# set azure function time trigger programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to write a c# Azure Function working on a time trigger in which the schedule would be variable, i.e. each function run would determine the time of the next run and thus should be able to change the scheduled time of the next trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a queue trigger with a queue output for this thanks to the [`NextVisibleTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage.nextvisibletime.aspx) property, it's a better choice than attempting to modify the timer schedule every run.

It also supports configurable retries upon failure (and a poison queue) so it's more durable than a timer trigger. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#handling-poison-queue-messages)

Comment: thanks, will implement and revert, question, what happens if the function fails? would it be no next trigger and thus the process stop?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#handling-poison-queue-messages

Comment: Wondering, is there a similar kind of feature available for Service Bus Topic, where I could process a topic's message by an Azure function based on a time interval?