# How to change content dynamically after function is called in Azure function app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop an Azure function app using Azure function v3.0. I implemented a time-triggered function. I want to change the content "schedule" in the `function.json`:

`function.json` file:

[image]

Comment: You can just edit the `schedule` on local in your vs 2019 and then publish it to azure.

Comment: I want to change the value dynamically when the time trigger function is called

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115985/c-sharp-set-azure-function-time-trigger-programmatically

Comment: I explain the principle of this problem very clearly, because only modifying the `function.json` file does not change the execution interval, so it is not necessary.

Comment: Also find a way for you to modify the file, but it won't work. The suggestion is to look at @RyanThomas ’s suggestion, or cancel the idea of doing so, directly modify the code, redeploy will do.

Comment: Currently azure should be updated. My previous method is ok, but it is not feasible at present.

Comment: It is not recommended to modify `function.json`, and I explained the principle of compilation very clearly. If it is helpful to you, can you accept it as answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927902/timer-triggered-function-in-azure-function-app-c/66929552#66929552

Comment: Remind you again that modifying the function.json file will also modify the `.dll` of the released file, that is, the TimerTrigger time you modified will not take effect.

Comment: I have updated my answer, use the command line to release the program, you can modify the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My previous answer is indeed correct, when I operate. After a lot of testing, I think it is because of the official Microsoft update. If you are also interested, you can try to use the previous azure function for testing.*

**Remind you again that modifying the function.json file will also modify the `.dll` of the released file, that is, the TimerTrigger time you modified will not take effect.**

## Let me describe my latest progress.

1. Create a new azure function. You can also use the previous ones, remember to delete the two configurations `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` and `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

   [image]
2. Use the `func azure functionapp publish function_app_name --csharp --nozip --force` command to publish your function app.
   step 1. Use cd command enters the folder that contains the `host.json` file.

   [image]

   step 2. Use `func azure functionapp publish function_app_name --csharp --nozip --force` to deploy your function app.

   [image]

   If there is an error message in the middle, you can ignore it. My screenshot shows `NativeCommandError`. As long as the final result has Upload completed successfully.

   [image]
3. Open the scm website or use App Service Editor (Preview)
   ,carry out testing.

   [image]
4. Check whether the function can run normally, and it can run normally after testing.

   [image]

## PREVIOUS

I recreate a func, and find I can't modify function.json now. [Maybe it fixed in 4.1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/updated-app-service-authentication-portal-experience-is-now-generally-available/).

**Now it impossible to create a new one and modify it.**

**Below function I created before.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a way for you to modify the function.js file, but the modification will not take effect.

**Principle:**

When we use vs2019 for publishing, this line in the code

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

After compiling, the `.dll` file is generated. The generated `function.json` file is only the properties and content of this Function. After the modification, the `.dll` file will not be modified so it will not take effect.

**The above conclusions are drawn through testing.**

**How to realize that the function.json file can be modified**

1. Add `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`.

   [image]
2. Delete the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE configuration`, or modify it to `0`.
3. Refresh the scm site, if the files under wwwroot are deleted, please use vs2019 redeploy function app.
4. Repeat the second step, and then modify the `function.json` file to succeed.

   [image]

## The above is only allowed to modify the content after the release, the modified time does not take effect, because the .dll has not been modified.

Comment: I have changed what you edit the above answer  so that my file is deleted automatically

Comment: @Muthumani SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true This configuration should be configured before release, so now you only need to re-release with vs2019, and then delete this configuration, you can modify the file.

Comment: I have tried this also but the function is delete

Comment: @Muthumani I know, I mean you should redeploy again by vs2019.

Comment: @Muthumani The content under wwwroot has been deleted, because the settings of step1 should be configured before deploying function app by vs2019.

Comment: @Muthumani After redeployed app,delete run from package,then you can modify function.json like my gif.

Comment: I redeployed the app and set it to 0 runs from the package then it shows "Use your local development environment to edit this Function App. This Function App was created in a local environment and cannot be edited in the Azure portal."

Comment: @Muthumani Can you show me the gif what you have done.

Comment: @Muthumani Maybe you need update your vs2019.

Comment: Can i have your mail for further details?

Comment: @Muthumani Sorry, I can’t. You can raise a support ticket on portal, let msft explain and help you. My solution after testing then get the answer. On Monday. I will update my answer with gif. Hope you can accept it.

Comment: when I run this command "func azure functionapp publish function_app_name --csharp --nozip --force" i got error following like this "func : The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

Comment: @Muthumani https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1218

Comment: @Muthumani https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1294

Comment: @Muthumani You need install func in your pc.

Comment: after installing the "func" following error:You are using an outdated version of the Azure Functions Core Tools. For more information, please see: https://aka.ms/func-v2-upgrade
Unable to connect to Azure. Make sure you have the `az` CLI or `Az.Accounts` PowerShell module installed and logged in and try again

Comment: it works for me when publish app using powershell.thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Change of function.json after deployment would not help at any time as the .dll does not get updated. rather redeployment is a better option.

for more read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#function-code