# Timer-triggered function in Azure function app (C#)

Tags: c#, azure-functions

In my Azure function app, I have two timer-triggered functions; one function is enabled and the other is disabled in `local.settings.json` (by specifying: `AzureWebjobs.function2.Disabled= "true"`).

I want to change the disabled function to be enabled programmatically.

This is my function app

```
public  class Function1
{        
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  void  Run1([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("function1");
        }

        [FunctionName("Function3")]
        public void Run2([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("function2");
        }
}
```

and this is my `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "AzureWebJobs.Function2.Disabled": "true"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy-paste your code into the question's body, then select the entire code section, and press the code format button in the button bar at the top of the editor to make your code look good on the page.

Comment: provide your code in the question, please!

Comment: @vaheeds, I have attached my code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can programmatically change the state , since it's lying on the runtime stack, therefore one of the option is using `Azure CLI`, you may use something below.

`az functionapp config appsettings set --name <myFunctionApp> --resource-group <myResourceGroup> --settings AzureWebJobs.<<Function Name>>.Disabled=true`

Note: If you send false, it will enable the Function.